# Restricted Selection dGrid data

Tags: dojo, selection, rows, dgrid

I have a grid created with dGrid with the "Pagination" extension end I needto click on the check-all checkbox on the header of dgrid and selecting only the rows in the current page leaving the rows of the other pages not checked!!!

Is it possible this???

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box. But I had the same requirement in a different situation and added a new method to my grid.

This code will check all visible for user checkboxes in the grid. I think it should work in your situation also. Add this to your grid and call `grid.checkAll()`

```
checkAll:function(){
    this._selected = []; 
    this.clearSelection();

    array.forEach(query("input[type=checkbox]",this.contentNode), function(input, i){
        var isVisible = input.offsetWidth > 0 || input.offsetHeight > 0;  //check if row checkbox is visible for user
        if(isVisible){
            var row = this.row(input.parentNode);
            if (this._selected.indexOf(row) == -1){
                this._selected.push(row);
            }

            input.checked = true;
            input.setAttribute("aria-checked", true);
        }
    },this);
},
```